# appengine safer dispatch.yaml routing to modules / services

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-modules

This is a basic sense check question as i'm deploying a few new modules:

dispatch.yaml:

```
application: my-app
# No version required; this does routing independent of version.

dispatch:
  # Default module serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    module: default

  # Default module serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "simple-sample.appspot.com/"
    module: default

  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
  - url: "*/mobile/*"
    module: mobile-frontend

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/work/*"
    module: static-backend
```

Wouldn't it be safer to put `"*.com/mobile/*"` instead of `"*/mobile/*"` ? In case other modules could use `/mobile/` in their urls somewhere and accidentally get routed to `mobile-frontend`?

What if I have domain names other than `.com` e.g. `.io`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could be considered safer in the way you're looking at it.

For the additional `.io` (or other) domains you can add a rule for each of those suffixes:

```
- url: "*.com/mobile/*"
  module: mobile-frontend
- url: "*.io/mobile/*"
  module: mobile-frontend
```

Side note: you don't actually *need* to specify the rules for the `default` module - all requests not matching any rules in the dispatch files are by default routed to the `default` module, making such rules redundant. You can test this by making a request not matching any of your `dispatch.yaml` rules and watching the `default` module's logs.

Comment: Thanks I'll do as you say, seems the right approach. (one for each domain). Yeah I figured any non matches would go to the default, was a fun test to make sure my entire site didn't go down :)

Comment: Keep in mind there's a limitation on the number of entries in the dispatch.yaml (afaik, it's 10)

Comment: yup it's 10... and this puts me at 8...  :)

Comment: also, i don't have SSL for some custom domains, but some modules are https (secure:always), which caused the site to not be reached in some cases.